# Problem with mist Wallet 0.7.6 (Beta 20) "vulnerability release"

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, wallets, synchronization, softfork

After updating to [Wallet 0.7.6 (Beta 20)](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.7.6), running mist start syncing mainnet from the beginning, which is very bad, because syncing ~1,7MBlocks took me 4 days last time ...

Is that due to the "vulnerability release" ? Can I speed up the sync (... no, 'geth --fast' doesn't help).

It also give me ntp server errors which I didn't get with Wallet 0.7.5,
here it is a log snippet:

```
[2016-06-26 22:32:27.913] [ERROR] main - Couldn't get time from NTP time sync server. Error: can't find 'ntp enabled:' line in timedatectl output
    at /home/lsoave/Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-7-6/resources/app.asar/node_modules/os-timesync/index.js:47:19
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:205:7)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:492:12)
Error: can't find 'ntp enabled:' line in timedatectl output
    at /home/lsoave/Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-7-6/resources/app.asar/node_modules/os-timesync/index.js:47:19
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:205:7)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:492:12)
```

**NOTE:** crossposted [here](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/891#issue-162345998)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs using **Geth Version: 1.5.0-unstable** with **mist Wallet 0.7.6 (Beta 20) “vulnerability release”**.

With **Geth Version: 1.4.8-stable** and **Wallet 0.7.6** syncing blockchain is **"A LOT"** faster:

### syncing ~1,7MBlocks took 1.45 h instead of 4 days!

That seems due to the  current develop branch, which will break backwards compatibility with 1.4.8 and earlier (see also https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/891#event-704742747)